# Entity Framework EDMX Relationship Mapping Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a users table and a roles table.

To link the two together I have created a UsersInRoles table which has a foreign key to the Users' UserId and another foreign key to the Roles' RoleName.

However, when I generate an EDMX from the database instead of a separate table for UsersInRoles, an association is created instead. Should I be using this association or should I try to figure out how to get the UsersInRoles table to be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of Entity Framework. The tables used to create n - n relationships are not created in the model as entities(The tables used as a middle table to create a relationship between two tables).

Instead you will observe an n to n relationship between `Users` and `Roles` entities.